# How to evaluate the integral of ln abs (sinx)/(1+x²) from 0 to infinity?

Tags: integration, fourier-series, absolute-value

This is a random integral equation I’ve thought suddenly.I know ln(sinx) has a Fourier series but I don’t know how to deal with the absolute value

I’ve tried many times but I still can’t do it